# Querying CSV with Grouped section

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, csv, t-sql

I am trying to transform the below listed source data to a table format. This source data gets loaded to a SQL table.

Source CSV :

```
Id:,27
Batch,Charges,Net
1212,34,"876,388.25"
23236,3627,"2,058,777.01"
Id:,28
Batch,Charges,Net
1212,1509,"876,388.25"
23236,3627,"2,058,777.01"
Id:,29
Batch,Charges,Net
1212,1509,"876,388.25"
23236,3627,"2,058,777.01"
```

Transform to this :

```
Id, Batch, Charges, Net
27, 1212,1509,"876,388.25"
27, 2346,3627,"2,058,777.01"
28, 1212,1509,"876,388.25"
28, 4443,3627,"2,058,777.01"
```

I tried PIVOT but it is getting more complicated and not giving the expected ouput. I am using T-SQL - SQL Server

Comment: What database is it? The `sql` tag is generic.

Comment: @GregPavlik T-SQL - SQL Server

Comment: SQL Server doesn't do string transformation operations very well because that's not its intended purpose. Have you considered using an external process (like, say, a PowerShell script) to transform the data to a more reasonable format before reading it in to SQL Server?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, thanks for the input. If there is no option I thought of introducing a custom code. Before that I wanted to give it a try in SQL.

Comment: @pili     Is this data coming from a file or something else?

Comment: @JeffModen yeah it is coming as a CSV file